# ASP.NET MVC Multiple Projects migrating to One Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I was wondering if its possible to have multiple Entity Framework Code First Projects migrating onto a single Database? I've tried looking and found [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects) but I think the instructions were kind of vague, so I made a list:

1. Done (created a new class library)
2. Does the new class library have to reference my project? Isn't it the other way around?
3. What are model snapshot files? Do I move my models also?
4. Where is this located? Is it in the class library?
5. What is the startup assembly? Is it my initial project that was referenced by the class library?
6. Add-Migration NewMigration -Project MyApp.Migrations (What is MyApp.Migrations)